# Create typed array from part of a binary buffer Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, typed-arrays

I have a binary buffer, the first half contains data meant to be read as an int using the Uint32 view. The second half is meant to be read as a char using the Uint8 view.

However the problem is the length of the char data is never guaranteed to be divisible by 4.

So if the length of the int data is 7, and the length of the char data is 5 then when I go to make the arrays I get a response like this:

```
 var Unit8Array = new Uint8Array(buffer);
 var Unit32Array = new Uint32Array(buffer);
 console.log(Unit8Array.length) // 32; (It's 32 because 7*4 + 5 = 32)
 console.log(Uint32Array.length) // Error Array Buffer out of bounds
```

So as you can see I can't create the Uint32 array because the entire buffer isn't divisible by the size of an Int. However I only need the first half of the data in that Uint32 array.

Is there any way to fix this problem without creating a new buffer? For performance reasons I was hoping to read the same data in memory just using different views or separating the buffer (meaning multiple downloads, as I get this buffer from an xhr request).

I tried to do this:

```
 var uint8Array= new Uint8Array(buffer);
 var padding = uint8Array.length + (4 - uint8Array%4);
 var uint32Array = new Uint32Array(buffer- padding);
```

But that just makes uint32Array be undefined.

Comment: You don't need to construct a `uint8Array` to get the buffer length, you can access `buffer.byteLength` directly. Also, I'm not sure what you expected to happen when using `uint8Array` as an operand to `%` and `buffer` as an operand to `-`

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Getting the length of the buffer isn't the problem. The problem is the length isn't divisible by 4 so no int array can be made from it. What I hoped to do with the padding variable was figure out how much the array needed chopped off to be divisible by 4. Then I tried to chop off that amount from the buffer using "buffer - padding" but it didn't work

Comment: Yes I understand what you're trying to accomplish. I'm saying you seem to be forgetting that `buffer` is an object and not a number. You can't subtract `padding` from `buffer`, and you can't pass a number to `Uint32Array()` constructor to initialize it with a reference to any particular buffer.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Yes I figured out you can't subtract a number from an object, but I thought to post it as something I tried. So is there anyway to build an int array from this buffer?

Comment: Hope you find my answer useful. If you're interested, I've also published an npm module called [`c-struct-js`](https://github.com/patrickroberts/c-struct-js) for manipulating structured data similarly to C structs and unions. You may find it useful for encapsulating the data structure you're trying to represent in JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to initialize a `Uint32Array` from the largest aligned segment of a given array buffer, you can do this:

```
var byteLength = buffer.byteLength;
var alignment = Uint32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT;
var alignedLength = byteLength - (byteLength % alignment);
var alignedBuffer = buffer.slice(0, alignedLength);
var uint32Array = new Uint32Array(alignedBuffer);
```